# How to use animations in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I want to use button animations in my selection but I don't know how .I want to use animation in android studio is there any way??
I searched a lot in YouTube, but I couldn't find a way. Is there a special library or a special site?

Answer (score 1):

Сreate a directory "anim" in "res" and put animations in it

There is a lot of information about this on the Internet, you searched badly and yet I will give you the code:

```
//variable:

Animation scaleUp, scaleDown;

scaleUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scale_up);
scaleDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scale_down);



Button Start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    Start.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        Start.startAnimation(scaleUp);
            }else if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        Start.startAnimation(scaleDown);
                       //write button action here
            }
            return true;
        }
});
```

Animation code "scaleUp"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromXScale="1"
  android:fromYScale="1"
  android:toXScale="1.2"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:toYScale="1.2"
  android:duration="100">
  </scale>
</set>
```

Animation code "scaleDown"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="1.2"
    android:fromYScale="1.2"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:duration="100">
</scale>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation).
Just make an **animation-list**. Take it in backgraound your button.
And use it

```
(view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_save).background as AnimationDrawable).start()
```